# How to pass data from anchor tag in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have a form in laravel on whos submission the following methods run:

```
public function validateSave() {
        $qualitycheck = new QualityCheck();
        $qualitycheck['site-name'] = Request::input('site-name');
        $qualitycheck['favicon'] = Request::has('favicon');
        $qualitycheck['title'] = Request::has('title');
        $qualitycheck['image-optimization'] = Request::has('image-optimization');
        $qualitycheck->save();
        Session::flash('quality-data', $qualitycheck);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

So i have the below line that passes the data to the next page:

```
Session::flash('quality-data', $qualitycheck);
```

But what i would really want to do is, when the form is submitted, i would really just want to show a link on the next page , which will be coded like so:

```
@if(Session::has('quality-data'))
        <a href="">Submited Quality Check</a>
@endif
```

Now on click on the link , i would like to show a view with all the data that the user submitted in the form , How do i do this ? I.E. How do i pass the data form from the `<a>` to the view that will show up when clicked on the `<a>` ??

So just to put things into perspective, this is how it works now:

```
STEP-1 :: User submits form , data is flashed to next page.  
STEP-2 :: Data user submits is shown on this page.
```

How i want it to work is:

```
STEP-1 :: User submits form , data is flashed to next page.
STEP-2 :: A link is shown to the user(Only if user clicks on the link we move to the next step).
STEP-3 :: Data user submited in first step is shown on this page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you code, please follow the below coding practices.

1. Prefer using `create()` function of model.
2. Put all your request data that is to be used in one variable (like `$input`)
3. Prefer using route names like `route('route.name')` instead of strings inside `redirection()` function.

Please replace your function with

```
public function validateSave() {
  $inputs = [
    'site-name' => request()->get('site_name'),
    'favicon' => request()->has('facvicon'),
    'title' => request()->has('title'),
    'image-optimization' => request()->has('image-optimization')
  ]);

  $qualityCheck = QualityCheck::create($inputs);

  $flashMessage = '<a href=' . route('quality.check.show', $qualityCheck) . '>Submitted Quality Check</a>'

  Session::flash('quality-data', $flashMessage);

  return redirect(route('home.index'));
}
```

And ensure you have something like this in your routes file.

```
Route::get('quality-check/{id}', 'QualityCheckController')->name('quality.check.show');
```

Let me know if something doesn't work...

Comment: is that last line getting a view `->name('quality.check.show');` ??

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik No, you are just giving a name to the route so you can use something like `route('quality.check.show', $qualitycheck)` to call it from anywhere...

Comment: one last thing bro , can you link in you answer to the route method because i seem to be finding the wrong route method in the laravel docs.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Unable to understand? What exactly are you unable to find about `route`?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one.

<a href="{{url('routename')}}">
```